# Webforms socket timeout

Tags: webforms

Webforms `Webservicetransport.jar` throws an `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out` exception when calling our webservice. This happens with larger forms (many fields), smaller forms work fine. The exception occurs within `5-9` secs.

Is there a way to set the timeout to a higher value?
Or does anyone know a solution?